# SELECT and UPDATE in stored procedure called from Excel with VBA

Tags: t-sql, excel, vba

I have created a stored procedure that involves a simple UPDATE and then SELECT statement, which works fine in SSMS - the update works and the select produces a recordset.

The problem is when I am trying:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset             'works fine
conn.Open sConnString                    'works fine
Set rs = conn.Execute("EXEC uspUpdateManual")
```

I get a 'operation is not allowed when the object is closed 3704' error.  If I comment out the update part of the stored procedure, the select works fine on its own and the recordset is dropped into Excel.

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateManual] 
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE Table1
    SET ACC = '9'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM Table1
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Is there any way to do both update and select in one, or do I have to separate these into two stored procedures?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem possibly here is with transactions, could you show the procedure code please?. You could try and wrap the update in a transaction and the select in another as show below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE...

COMMIT TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT...

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought the same initially and tried wrapping the update.  I've just tried wrapping the select as well, but still get the same error.  I've added the procedure code to the question.

Comment: alternatively have you tried to wrap them both inside one transaction?

Comment: Still getting the same error when they are a single transaction

Comment: I ended up using two separate procedures, which is a bit messy, but it works.  Do you have any other suggestions that I might try?